# Need to get match and mismatch result from two lists

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['ram', 'krishna', 'venkat','naran', 'vishnu']
list2 = ['ram', 'siva', 'venkat','sankar']


res = []
for li in list1:
    if li in list2:
        res.append((li, 'success'))
    else:
        res.append((li,'fail'))
print(res)

Result: [('ram', 'success'), ('krishna', 'fail'), ('venkat', 'success'), ('naran', 'fail'), ('Vishnu', 'fail')]
```

I need to match with the lists, list1 is fixed and need to match the
list2 with list1 and need below results with success/fail. Please help!

```
ram      ram        Success
krishna  siva       Fail
venkat   venkat     Success
naran    sankar     Fail
vishnu              Not available
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: sorry missed my script i have updated the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
import itertools
list1 = ['ram', 'krishna', 'venkat','naran', 'vishnu']
list2 = ['ram', 'siva', 'venkat','sankar']
final_data = '\n'.join(["{}   {}   {}".format(a, b, ['Fail', 'Success'][a == b]) if None not in (a, b) else "{}    Not available".format(filter(None, (a, b))[0]) for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2)])
```

Output:

```
ram   ram   Success
krishna   siva   Fail
venkat   venkat   Success
naran   sankar   Fail
vishnu    Not available
```